# Django admin interface broken after bower install

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I am using Django for my backend. Recently I installed and configured django-admin-tools-stats to generate graphs etc. I followed instructions as mentioned here: https://github.com/areski/django-admin-tools-stats

However after configuring bower my admin UI broke completely (I ca do everything but the awesome UI is gone)[image]

My folder structure looks like following:
[image]

My settings.py:

```
#Added for bower
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), ".."),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
# Specify path to components root (you need to use absolute path)
BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'components')

BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
'jquery#2.0.3',
'jquery-ui#~1.10.3',
'd3#3.3.6',
'nvd3#1.1.12-beta',
)

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)

TEMPLATES = [
{  
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    #'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.request',
        ],
        'loaders': (
            'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
            #'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
            #'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
            'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        ),
    },
 },
]
```

INSTALLED_APPS contains `'admin_tools','admin_tools.theming','admin_tools.menu','admin_tools.dashboard', 'admin_tools_stats', 'django_nvd3','djangobower'`

What is wrong here?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes! It asked me do I want to override and I said yes. What exactly does it do? Also,  what role this bower installation does play in tools-stats, why is it needed? I commented out bower related code from my settings.py and everythings looks fine again.